# Firebase search for grandchildren

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database is looking like this:

```
\myapp\
 \users\
  \UID\
   \username\
```

When I try to check if the user's username exist, I use this code:

```
func checkForUsername()
{
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("username"){
            print("username exist")
        }else{
            print("username does not exist")
        }
    })
}
```

However, it always return the username does not exist print... Maybe it is because username is a grandchild of users? How can I fix this?

Small other question: Is this setup the best way to start if I also want to check if the username is already taken by other users?

Comment: If your database structure is correct, that reference wouldn't exist. You skipped `\users`. Have you checked the contents of `snapshot` to see if there is anything there?

Comment: How do you mean the reference wouldn't exist? I already said the print always return "username does not exist". When I try print(snapshot), I do not see anything in the debug description...

Comment: Your data structure shows that the name would be at `myapp\users\UID\username` but your reference points to `myapp\UID\username`. You left out "users" in the child path.

Comment: Try ref.toString to see the actual URL you've constructed. Type that into the browser with .json at the end and see what data is at that path. The data will be null and the path will probably not look like what you've expected. First and foremost, output the value of FIRAuth.auth().currentUser (that's probably null, too and it's probably a timing issue). Also, there's not enough here to diagnose. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TravisChristian how can I change the path to \myapp\users\UID\username ?

Comment: I misspoke before, the reference would exist but it would contain no data as there is no value at that path. In this case you would need `ref.child("users").child(...` but try what Kato says to verify what you're actually looking up before continuing.